# Unable to run iisexpress on windows 11 on parallels VM

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express, parallels

[image: Error in visual studio 2022]

[image: Error in command prompt]

Tried to run iisexpress both from Visual Studio 2022 and Command Prompt. Tried reinstalling IIS but same error.

Note: I am running the windows 11 in a M1 Macbook pro using Parallels.

Comment: You can learn the background from my post, https://halfblood.pro/successful-and-failed-attempt-my-first-pull-request-for-asp-net-core/ So, the IIS issues can be easily resolved by using the workaround I offered. I didn't have time to apply the same to IIS Express yet.

Comment: @LexLi Can you please clarify what I'm supposed to do and if I have to do anything extra for IIS Express? I read your blog post but didn't get most of it since I'm a university freshman still learning to code. I tried changing the "Enable emulation on arm64" setting in the application pool but the problem remains. 
Also, note that I'm trying to locally run (not deployed on any server) an old project done in the .NET framework (not .NET core).
Thank you so much for your time and comment!

Comment: If that's too much for you, try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77238733/iisexpress-not-starting-on-arm64-mac-net-4-8/77239036#77239036

Comment: Ran into a few more problems but finally got it to work. Thank you so much!! @LexLi