# IISExpress not starting on ARM64 Mac / .NET 4.8

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, iis-express, parallels

I run Visual Studio Community Edition 2022 on a M2 Mac under Parallels with Windows 11 for ARM64.

I got the application (.NET 4.8 Webforms) running on the local IIS, but not on IIS Express. IISExpress startup fails with "Error loading global modules".

```
PS C:\Program Files\IIS Express> .\iisexpress.exe /trace:error
Starting IIS Express ...
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 1389375
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 1389390
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 1389390
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 1389390
Failed processing with hr = 8007007e
Error loading global modules.  hr = 8007007e
Terminating W3_SERVER object
Start listenerChannel http:0
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 1390546
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 1390546
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 1390546
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 1390546
Failed processing with hr = 8007007e
Error loading global modules.  hr = 8007007e
Terminating W3_SERVER object
InitComplete event signalled
Process Model Shutdown called
Waiting for all LISTENER_CHANNELS to stop
Unable to start iisexpress.

Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
For more information about the error, run iisexpress.exe with the tracing switch enabled (/trace:error)
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS Express ships with ASP.NET Core module by default. However, due to [a known issue](https://halfblood.pro/successful-and-failed-attempt-my-first-pull-request-for-asp-net-core/) the bitness of ASP.NET Core module shipped in its ARM64 installer was wrong and that's the cause of this error you described.

While the ultimate fix should be a patched installer, which might not come quickly, you can open the applicationHost.config file (hidden in `.vs` folder of your project folder) and delete ASP.NET Core module from the module list manually.